# R Ggplot2: changing histogram y axis to decimal places

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am trying to change the y axis (Proportion) of the right histogram into decimal places like the left histogram using ggplot. I tried using geom_histogram(aes(y=..ncount..) but the bars end up squashed. Any other suggestions?

Help desperately needed!

Thanksss

[image: Code]

[image: Histograms]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Do not post images of code or data. We cannot copy/paste images into R for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an example using the `mtcars` dataset. To change the y-axis decimals to what you want, you should use the `scales` package which has the function `number_format`. If you run the following command `number_format(accuracy = 0.1)` in the labels of `scale_y_continuous` you will get the right decimals. You can use the following code as an example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..count../sum(..count..))) +
  ylab("Proportion") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 0.1))
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see, the decimals for the y-axis are in the right format.